# Inequality for Expected Value of a Convex Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $X$ be random variable with $-1 < X < X_\max$ and $X_{\max} >0$ and take $a = \min\{1, \frac{1}{X_{max} }\}$, I was wondering is the following inequality hold
>   $$
> E\left[ {\frac{X}{{1 - aX}}} \right] \leq 0 ?
> $$

I recognized that the function $f(x) = x/(1-ax)$ is convex in $x$ but the Jensen's inequality goes another direction and doesn't help. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $X = \frac{1}{2}$ and $X_{\max} > \frac{1}{2}$. Then $a \in (0,1]$ and so
\begin{align*}
aX \le X =\frac{1}{2} \implies 1 - aX \ge \frac{1}{2} >0.
\end{align*}
Thus the random variable $\frac{X}{1-aX}$ is strictly positive, and so is it expectation.

For a more general answer, if $X >0$, then we have
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}1 -aX \ge 1 - X >0 & X < 1 \\
1-aX \ge 1 - \frac{X}{X_\max} >0 & X \ge 1 \end{cases}
\end{align*}
So $\frac{X}{1-aX}>0$, and thus it expectation is positive.